# Get generated client-side html code in to my app

Tags: javascript, c++, parsing, winapi, browser

I have following problem. I enter a website by browser. The site is using javascript, so some of code is genereted in browser. I want to receive that extra code(if cant it may be whole generated html)  in my program. Javascript parser is not good solution in this case because script use random variables to draw the number. It must be the same variable as in the browser. I appreciate any advice, I write in c++, but other languages' solution would be great as well. 
PS I am writing something like bot to automatically use site and I send commands to browser by winapi. If you know better solution, go ahead

Please give me any suggestions.